# Why my post method only send 1 row of table data after I added the htacess file?

Tags: mysql, database, .htaccess, post, methods

`post` method only send 1 row of my table after I remove the extension file (`.php`) using `.htaccess` file.

if I remove the `.htaccess` file it will run normally. This my **.htaccess** file.

```
DirectoryIndex index

RewriteEngine on

#remove .php extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

#add back the .php extension (ex: include 'index.php')
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]

#add the .html extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

The `post` data should send all the row of data

Comment: You should not do _external_ redirects for POST requests, you lose your actual POST data that way when the browser follows the redirect by making a _GET_ request.

Comment: so i need to change to from POST to GET ?

Comment: No, you should just leave POST requests alone, and not externally rewrite them. Try and make those go to the correct URL in the first place, wherever you are in control of that (i.e., your own form actions etc.) - and live with it that the URL might stay “ugly”, if you get POST requests from external sources where you can’t control which URL they use.

Answer (score 0):

One missing part in .htaccess is the `RewriteBase /` , otherwise .php stripped url when u take *.php will not work.

Regarding the data not posted up, could you please check the **form action** and ensure there is no php extension in it. If the form action has .php extension, then on submitting, htaccess redirect to url without .php so the data get ignored.

i.e. if your form is like

**`<form action="save.php" method="post">`**

then replace that with

**`<form action="save" method="post">`**

Comment: _“One missing part in .htaccess is the RewriteBase / , otherwise .php stripped url when u take *.php will not work.”_ - that’s not true, a RewriteBase is not automatically necessary for this to work.

Comment: Hi Sajeer, Thank you for your response.. I already did like you said. but it still only send 1 row. the others row are still lost. do you have any other idea ?

Comment: @misorude, if rewritebase is not there then the full path will be taken based on apache configuration, I tested that

Comment: and I never said it is mandatory in this case, just told the it would be better to have that

Comment: @Mohamad Hazim Johari, can you share the form element?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function print_today() {
  // ***********************************************
  // AUTHOR: WWW.CGISCRIPT.NET, LLC
  // URL: http://www.cgiscript.net
  // Use the script, just leave this message intact.
  // Download your FREE CGI/Perl Scripts today!
  // ( http://www.cgiscript.net/scripts.htm )
  // ***********************************************
  var now = new Date();
  var months = new Array('January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December');
  var date = ((now.getDate()<10) ? "0" : "")+ now.getDate();
  function fourdigits(number) {
    return (number < 1000) ? number + 1900 : number;
  }
  var today =  date + " " + months[now.getMonth()] + " " + (fourdigits(now.getYear()));
  return today;
}



// from http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/number/round.html
function roundNumber(number,decimals) {
  var newString;// The new rounded number
  decimals = Number(decimals);
  if (decimals < 1) {
    newString = (Math.round(number)).toString();
  } else {
    var numString = number.toString();
    if (numString.lastIndexOf(".") == -1) {// If there is no decimal point
      numString += ".";// give it one at the end
    }
    var cutoff = numString.lastIndexOf(".") + decimals;// The point at which to truncate the number
    var d1 = Number(numString.substring(cutoff,cutoff+1));// The value of the last decimal place that we'll end up with
    var d2 = Number(numString.substring(cutoff+1,cutoff+2));// The next decimal, after the last one we want
    if (d2 >= 5) {// Do we need to round up at all? If not, the string will just be truncated
      if (d1 == 9 && cutoff > 0) {// If the last digit is 9, find a new cutoff point
        while (cutoff > 0 && (d1 == 9 || isNaN(d1))) {
          if (d1 != ".") {
            cutoff -= 1;
            d1 = Number(numString.substring(cutoff,cutoff+1));
          } else {
            cutoff -= 1;
          }
        }
      }
      d1 += 1;
    } 
    if (d1 == 10) {
      numString = numString.substring(0, numString.lastIndexOf("."));
      var roundedNum = Number(numString) + 1;
      newString = roundedNum.toString() + '.';
    } else {
      newString = numString.substring(0,cutoff) + d1.toString();
    }
  }
  if (newString.lastIndexOf(".") == -1) {// Do this again, to the new string
    newString += ".";
  }
  var decs = (newString.substring(newString.lastIndexOf(".")+1)).length;
  for(var i=0;i<decimals-decs;i++) newString += "0";
  //var newNumber = Number(newString);// make it a number if you like
  return newString; // Output the result to the form field (change for your purposes)
}

function update_total() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.price').each(function(i){
    price = $(this).html().replace("RM ","");
    if (!isNaN(price)) total += Number(price);
  });

  total = roundNumber(total,2);

  $('#subtotal').html("RM "+total);
  $('#total').html("RM "+total);
  
  update_balance();
}

function update_balance() {
  var due = $("#total").html().replace("RM ","") - $("#paid").val().replace("RM ","");
  due = roundNumber(due,2);
  
  $('.due').html("RM "+due);
}

function update_price() {
  var row = $(this).parents('.item-row');
  var price = row.find('.cost').val().replace("RM ","") * row.find('.qty').val();
  price = roundNumber(price,2);
  isNaN(price) ? row.find('.price').html("N/A") : row.find('.price').html("RM "+price);
  
  update_total();
}

function bind() {
  $(".cost").blur(update_price);
  $(".qty").blur(update_price);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 
  
  $('input').click(function(){
    $(this).select();
  });

  $("#paid").blur(update_balance);
  

  var count=1;
  $("#addrow").click(function(){
    count++;
    $(".item-row:last").after('<tr class="item-row"><td class="item-name" name="item[]"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea></textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td><td class="description" ><textarea name="desc[]">Location: </textarea></td><td style="width:90px;"><textarea class="cost" name="cost[]">RM 0.00</textarea></td><td style="width:30px;"><textarea class="qty" name="qty[]" style="width:100%; text-align: center;" >1</textarea></td><td style="width:90px;"><textarea name="price[]" class="price">RM 0.00</textarea></td></tr>');

    if ($(".delete").length > 0) $(".delete").show();
    bind();
  });
  
  bind();



  $(".delete").live('click',function(){
    $(this).parents('.item-row').remove();
    update_total();
    if ($(".delete").length < 1) $(".delete").hide();
  });
  
  $("#cancel-logo").click(function(){
    $("#logo").removeClass('edit');
  });
  $("#delete-logo").click(function(){
    $("#logo").remove();
  });
  $("#change-logo").click(function(){
    $("#logo").addClass('edit');
    $("#imageloc").val($("#image").attr('src'));
    $("#image").select();
  });
  $("#save-logo").click(function(){
    $("#image").attr('src',$("#imageloc").val());
    $("#logo").removeClass('edit');
  });
  
  $("#date").val(print_today());

  
});
```

```css
/*
  CSS-Tricks Example
  by Chris Coyier
  http://css-tricks.com
*/

* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { font: 14px/1.4 Georgia, serif; }
#page-wrap { width: 800px; margin: 0 auto; }

textarea { border: 0; font: 14px Georgia, Serif; overflow: hidden; resize: none; }
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
table td, table th {
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: left;
}



input[type=text] {
  width: 130px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

/* When the input field gets focus, change its width to 100% */
input[type=text]:focus {
  width: 100%;
}
textarea { border: 0; font: 14px Georgia, Serif; overflow: hidden; resize: none; }
#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png'); /* Add a search icon to input */
  background-position: 10px 12px; /* Position the search icon */
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the icon image */
  width: 100%; /* Full-width */
  font-size: 16px; /* Increase font-size */
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px; /* Add some padding */
  border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
  margin-bottom: 12px; /* Add some space below the input */
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse; /* Collapse borders */
  width: 100%; /* Full-width */
  border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
  font-size: 18px; /* Increase font-size */
}

#myTable th, #myTable td {
  text-align: left; /* Left-align text */
  padding: 12px; /* Add padding */
}

#myTable tr {
  /* Add a bottom border to all table rows */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; 
}

#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
  /* Add a grey background color to the table header and on hover */
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#header { height: 15px; width: 100%; margin: 20px 0; background: #222; text-align: center; color: white; font: bold 15px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; text-decoration: uppercase; letter-spacing: 20px; padding: 8px 0px; }

#address { width: 250px; height: 150px; float: left; }
#customer { overflow: hidden; }

#logo { text-align: right; float: right; margin-top: 25px; }
#customer-title { height: 90px; float: left; }

#meta { margin-top: 1px; width: 300px; float: right; }
#meta td { text-align: right;  }
#meta td.meta-head { text-align: left; background: #eee; }
#meta td textarea { width: 100%; height: 20px; text-align: right; }

#metas { margin-top: 1px; width: 800px; float: right; }
#metas td { text-align: right;  }
#metas td.metas-head { text-align: left; background: #eee; }
#metas td textarea { width: 100%; height: 20px; text-align: left; }


#items { clear: both; width: 100%; margin: 30px 0 0 0; border: 1px solid black; }
#items th { background: #eee; }
#items textarea { width: 80px; height: 50px; }
#items tr.item-row td { border: 0; vertical-align: top; }
#items td.description { width: 300px; }
#items td.item-name { width: 175px; }
#items td.jumlah { width: 30px; text-align: center; }

#items td.description textarea, #items td.item-name textarea, #items td.jumlah textarea { width: 100%; }
#items td.total-line { border-right: 0; text-align: right; }
#items td.total-value { border-left: 0; padding: 10px; }
#items td.total-value textarea { height: 20px; background: none; }
#items td.balance { background: #eee; }
#items td.blank { border: 0; }




#terms { text-align: center; margin: 20px 0 0 0; }
#terms h5 { text-transform: uppercase; font: 13px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; letter-spacing: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid black; padding: 0 0 8px 0; margin: 0 0 8px 0; }
#terms textarea { width: 100%; text-align: center;}

textarea:hover, textarea:focus, #items td.total-value textarea:hover, #items td.total-value textarea:focus, .delete:hover { background-color:#EEEEEE; }

.delete-wpr { position: relative; }
.delete { display: block; color: #000; text-decoration: none; position: absolute; background: #EEEEEE; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 3px; border: 1px solid; top: -6px; left: -22px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12px; }






  $(".delete").live('click',function(){
    $(this).parents('.item-row').remove();
    update_total();
    if ($(".delete").length < 1) $(".delete").hide();
  });
  
  $("#cancel-logo").click(function(){
    $("#logo").removeClass('edit');
  });
  $("#delete-logo").click(function(){
    $("#logo").remove();
  });
  $("#change-logo").click(function(){
    $("#logo").addClass('edit');
    $("#imageloc").val($("#image").attr('src'));
    $("#image").select();
  });
  $("#save-logo").click(function(){
    $("#image").attr('src',$("#imageloc").val());
    $("#logo").removeClass('edit');
  });
  
  $("#date").val(print_today());

  
});
```

```html
<?PHP 
if(isset($db,$_POST['save_btn']))
{ 
 $invoiceno=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['invoiceno']);
 $paid=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['paid']);
 $kosong="RM 0.00";
 $number = count($_POST["item"]);

 $check="SELECT * FROM sales2";
 $result=mysqli_query($db,$check);
 while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  if($row['invoiceno']==$invoiceno){
   $id=$row['id']; //store to session
         $del = "DELETE FROM sales2 WHERE id=$id";
         $dahdelete=true;
         mysqli_query($db,$del);
   
  }

 }


 
 
 for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++)
 {
  echo $_POST["item"][$i];
  if(trim($_POST["item"][$i] != '') || trim($_POST["desc"][$i] != '') || trim($_POST["qty"][$i] != '') || trim($_POST["cost"][$i] != '') || trim($_POST["price"][$i] != ''))
  {
   $checker=$i+1;
   if($number==$checker){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO sales2(invoiceno,date,item, descriptions, qty, cost, price, paid) VALUES('$invoiceno',CURDATE(),
    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["item"][$i]) ."',
    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["desc"][$i]) ."',
    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["qty"][$i])  ."',
    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["cost"][$i]) ."',
    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["price"][$i])."',
    '$paid' )";
    mysqli_query($db, $sql);
   }
   else{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO sales2(invoiceno,date,item, descriptions, qty, cost, price,paid) VALUES('$invoiceno',CURDATE(),
    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["item"][$i]) ."',
    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["desc"][$i]) ."',
    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["qty"][$i])  ."',
    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["cost"][$i]) ."',
    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["price"][$i])."','$kosong')";
    mysqli_query($db, $sql);
   }
   
   
  }
 }
 if ($dahdelete==false){
  $id=1;

  $updatetable= "UPDATE countertable SET no='$invoiceno' WHERE id=$id";
  mysqli_query($db,$updatetable);

 }
 
 #header("location:");
 

    
    
}

?>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="invoice.php" method="POST" role="form">
  <textarea id="header">INVOICE</textarea>
  
  <div id="identity">
            <textarea id="address" readonly>
 
ADDRESS:

Email: 
Phone: </textarea>

            
  
  </div>
  
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
  
  <div id="customer">

            <p style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; float: left; color: black;">MY COMPANY</p><br><br>
            <textarea style="width: 400px; height: 115px; float: left; font-size: 12px"  >


            </textarea>
  
  
            
            <table id="meta">
                <tr>
                    <td class="meta-head">Invoice #</td>
                    <td><textarea name="invoiceno" readonly><?php echo $invoice?></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td class="meta-head">Date</td>
                    <td><textarea name="date" id="date"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="meta-head">Amount Due</td>
                    <td><textarea class="due">RM 0.00</textarea></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
  
  </div>
  
  <table id="items"  >
  
    <tr>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Unit Cost</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr class="item-row">
        <td class="item-name"><textarea name="item[]"></textarea></td>
        <td class="description"><textarea name="desc[]" >Location:</textarea></td>
        <td><textarea name="cost[]" class="cost" style="width: 90px;">RM 0.00</textarea></td>
        <td style="width: 30px;"><textarea name="qty[]" class="qty" style="width: 100%; text-align: center;" >1</textarea></td>
        <td><textarea name="price[]" class="price" style="width: 90px;">RM 0.00</textarea></td>
    </tr>
    
  <tr id="hiderow">
    <td colspan="5"><a id="addrow" href="javascript:;" title="Add a row">Add a row</a>
    </td>
  </tr>

    
    

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="blank" > <textarea style="width: 500px; height:20px;"> </textarea></td>
        <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Subtotal</td>
        <td class="total-value"><textarea name="subtotal" id="subtotal" style="width: 90px;">RM 0.00</textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td colspan="2" class="blank"> <textarea style="width: 500px; height:20px;"></textarea></td>
        <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Total</td>
        <td class="total-value"><textarea name="total" id="total" style="width: 90px;">RM 0.00</textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="blank"><textarea style="width: 500px; height:20px;"></textarea></td>
        <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Amount Paid</td>

        <td class="total-value paid"><textarea name="paid" id="paid" style="width: 90px;">RM 0.00</textarea></td>
        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="blank"></td>
        <td colspan="2" class="total-line balance">Balance Due</td>
        <td class="total-value balance"><textarea name="due" class="due" style="width: 90px;">RM 0.00</textarea></td>
    </tr>
  
  </table>
  
  <div id="terms">
    <h5 ><b>Terms</b></h5>
    <textarea style="font-size: 13px; text-align: center;" ></textarea>
  </div>
  <br>
        <br>
        <center><div id="hiderow">        
        <button  title="save invoice" name="save_btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-info">&nbsp&nbsp Save Data &nbsp&nbsp</button>
        </div></center>
  </form>
```

Comment: I have edited this and added multiple rows, is this how your html source looks like? I edited the answer as I am not able to post large code in comment

Comment: yes .. but the actual is not exactly like that it has table header and footer and etc..

Comment: Then I might need the whole code to test at my side as this should work and working at my side without issue

Comment: See your addrow, `$("#addrow").click(function(){...`, the **name** attribute is not there in any of the `<textarea></textarea>`, then how would the form identify this element created and `$_POST["item"]` will not contain the newly added item. In any of the case this will not work